# Using bash what scripts or commands do you use to make you more productive?

Tags: bash, scripting

What scripts do you regularly use to improve your productivity?

Over the last year I have been trying to use bash scripts and commands to improve my productivity as a developer (Web and applications).  Here is a list of a few simple ones that I use:

Make files lower case:

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "`echo $i| tr [A-Z] [a-z]`"; done
```

Test whether a tag exists in subversion:

```
if [ "`svn ls http://www.mysvnserver.co.uk/myproject/tags | grep it-0.7.0.1/`" = "it-0.7.0.1/" ]; then echo YES; else echo NO; fi
```

Rename all JPG files in the current directory and add an increment:

```
j=16;for i in *.jpg; do mv "$i" "gallery_"$j".jpg"; j=$(($j+1)); done;ls
```

Fix a misspelling in a group of filenames:

```
for i in aples*.jpg; do mv $i ${i/aples/apples} ; done
```

For more see here:

[http://blog.emson.co.uk/2009/06/18-useful-bash-scripts-for-web-developers](http://blog.emson.co.uk/2009/06/18-useful-bash-scripts-for-web-developers/)

What scripts do you use?
Thanks...

Comment: You really need to learn to quote all your parameter expansions ($i, $foo -> "$i", "$foo").  If you don't, you're telling bash you want it to take the value of i or foo, and cut it apart, and then try to expand filenames from it!  That is not what you want.  Always quote your parameter expansions.

Answer (score 6):

You have a good source of such command at [**CommandLineFu**](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/tagged/34/bash).